# Calculate mean with a filter on a column's values

Tags: r

I've created this small data frame:

```
employee <- c('Yossi ','Pitt ','Deepak','Golan')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,91000)
testd <- data.frame(employee,salary)
```

When I write:

```
mean(testd$salary)
```

I get the right answer : 40550

But when I tried to calculate the mean for salaries that are greater than 25000 I get this outcome.

```
mean(testd$salary>=25000)
# [1] 0.5
```

and not 58900 that is made of this calculation: (26800+91000)/2

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
mean(testd$salary[testd$salary>=25000])
```

Actually `testd$salary>=25000` is a vector of `boolean` values, which are automatically mapped to `numeric` type (`True = 1`, `False = 0`) when you call `mean`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `dplyr` you can have the right answer with this code:

```
library(dplyr)
testd %.%
  select(employee, salary) %.%
  filter(salary > 25000) %.%
  summarise(mean = mean(salary))
```

Answer (score 3):

even if you're a beginner (as I am), I recommend starting to learn data.table as it will make your computations much faster compared to using regular data.frame. in this instance you could do (which also looks much cleaner) :

```
testd<-data.table(testd)
testd[salary>25000,mean(salary)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `aggregate` get the answer for both sides of your threshold:

```
aggregate(salary~salary>=25000,testd,mean)
  salary >= 25000 salary
1           FALSE  22200
2            TRUE  58900
```